# DEigenvalues and NDEigenvalues return different values

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, eigenvalues

In the following example, DEigenvalues and NDEigenvalues return different results despite having identical arguments. Does anyone know why?

(I use Mathematica 11.3)

```
DEigenvalues[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0,True]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 5] // N
NDEigenvalues[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}],DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0,True]}, 
 u[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 5]

(*
{-123.37, -101.163, -101.163, -83.8916, -83.8916}
{-4.93481, -12.3371, -12.3371, -19.7395, -24.6755}
*)
```

The two outputs are the same when I put a minus sign in front of the Laplacian.

Also, the smallest magnitude Eigenvalue returned by DEigenvalues changes when I change the number of Eigenvalues from 5 to, say, 10. (The docs state that DEigenvalues is supposed to return the n smallest magnitude Eigenvalues)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Increase 5 to 50 in your NDEigenvalues command.

Comment: The values somewhat agree, but still, DEigenvalues doesn't return the smallest magnitude Eigenvalues. Instead, it seems to list the actual smallest values in some range.

Comment: If you have a `-` inn front of the `Laplacian` things work as expected. But this looks fishy, I'd report it.

Comment: Done. I will keep you up to date.

Comment: I got a reply from tech support, they forwarded the issue to the developers.